# How to add header & footer with page number without affecting the other content while printing in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my page having a table while printing the page, it goes to 2 or more pages. I would like to print my header and footer on every page. I have tried some code but it takes the whole page as a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so rough, so I just can guess what problem which you meet.

Let's summary your question, you want to create a few pages with the table and keep the same header and footer for each page, right?

If it is, first you need to create a layout that fixes the header and footer and edit the content no matter what you want between header and footer.

In your case, the content area will be put on the table or something else you want, the rough code is show as below:

```
...


<body>
<header>
   ...header content
</header>
<main>
   <table>
      <thead> ... </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td></td>
               ...
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</main>
<footer>
   ...footer content
</footer>

</body>



...
```

Hope the above answer can make you pass through your problem.